# Compact subsets for a given topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, compactness

I am currently studying topology in real analysis and have a problem that I'm stuck on and really don't understand completely.

**Question:**

Consider the topology $ \tau$  = {$\emptyset$ ,$\mathbb{R}$}  $\cup$  {$ (a,\infty$)}$_{a \in \mathbb{R}}$  in  $\mathbb{R}$

**i) What are the compact subsets of ($\mathbb{R},\tau$}?**

I understand that a set is compact if every open cover has a finite subcover. So would the compact subsets of ($\mathbb{R},\tau$} just be the $\emptyset $?  As any open interval in $\mathbb{R} $ {$(a,\infty)$} does not have a finite subcover.  Not too sure if this is the correct... Am i wrong here?

**ii) What is an example of a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that is continuous wrt the topology in both the domain and co-domain such that
\begin{align}
 f(x) \leq -x      
\end{align}
$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} $  or does such a function even exist?**

Couldn't I just take the $f(x) = -x-1$ , then $-x-1 \leq -x$   or is this completely wrong?

I am new to topology and don't really have a strong understanding here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first part: consider a set of the form $(a,b), [a,b), [a,b] or (a,b]$ with $a,b$ reals or infinity or minus inifinity. See how is a cover with open sets if $a$ is not minus infinity. Can you take just one open set of that cover which contains your subset?

Comment: singletons are compact here.

Answer (score 4):

**i)** *Every* finite subset of any topological space is compact. You seem to be thinking that “subset” is the same thing as “an element of $\tau$”. Not true.

**ii)** There is no such function. Note that $f^{-1}\bigl((a,\infty)\bigr)=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)>a\}$. But, if $x\in f^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)$, then $-x\geqslant f(x)>a$. So, $f^{-1}\bigl((a,\infty)\bigr)$ consists only of numbers smaller than $-a$ and therefore it can only belong to $\tau$ if it is empty. But if you take $a>f(0)$, then it is clear that $0\in f^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)$ and therefore $f^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: i) I guess my confusion is how can I get a cover that essentially covers to infinity with finitely many subcovers. If I take the set $[a-i,a+i/2]$ ( let i go from 1 to infinity) that would eventually cover $(a,\infty)$ would that be a compact subset ? If this is true wouldnt there be infinitely many compact subsets for this topology. Sorry I dont quite understand here. ii) makes perfect sense thank you

Comment: You can't take $[a-i,a+i/2]$, the definition of compact is: $X$ is compact if every cover with open sets of $X$ have a finite subcover.  $[a-i,a+i/2]$ are not open in your topology. Every set of the form $(a,b), [a,b], (a,b],[a,b),(a,\infty)$ and $[a,\infty)$ are compacts. Check again the definition of compact, you are getting it wrong and that is causing your misconception.

Comment: Take $[0,1]$, for instance. Let $\{A_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ be an open cover of $[0,1]$. Then $0\in A_{\lambda_0}$, for some $\lambda_0\in\Lambda$. Therefore, $A_{\lambda_0}\neq\emptyset$, and so either $A_{\lambda_0}=\mathbb R$ or $A_{\lambda_0}=(a,\infty)$, for some $a<0$. And in **both** cases $\{A_{\lambda_0}\}$ is a finite subcover of $\{A_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$!

Answer (score 4):

The question is about compact subsets of $\Bbb R$, not compact subsets from the topology $\tau$, as you seem to think.

If a set $A$ has a minimum $m$ and we have an open cover of $A$ then some set $(a,\infty)$ from that open cover must contain $m$ and then that open set then contains all of $A$: $$x \in A \implies a < m \le x \implies x \in (a, \infty)$$

So sets with a minimum are compact: every open cover has a finite (one-element even) subcover.

On the other hand, if $A$ is non-empty and has no minimum, then either $m= \inf A$ is finite or $-\infty$. In the former case define $a_n = m+\frac{1}{n}$, in the latter $a_n = -n$ and then note that $\{(a_n, \infty): n \in \Bbb N)\}$ is an open cover of $A$ without a finite subcover.

So $A \subseteq (\Bbb R, \tau)$ is compact iff $\min A \in A$ exists.

Comment: So would this mean the compact sets would just be $(a,\infty)$ since it will just cover any set A ?

Comment: @Swag34214 No, a set like $A=[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ is compact, or $A=[0,\infty)$ etc. It's not the question which *open* subsets are compact!

Comment: Ahh I think I understand, the question is WHAT are the compact subsets in $\mathbb{R}$. So what you are saying is a condition for subsets to be compact in $\mathbb{R}$ is they must have a minimium allowing every open cover to have a finite subcover. Is this correct?. So the compact subsets are just any subset that have a minimium.  Is this idea similar to the idea that compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and bounded?

Comment: @Swag34214 Yes, a full characterisation of compact subsets like closed and bounded, but this topology is even simpler: just having a minimum makes it compact.

Comment: If $m=\inf A\in \Bbb R$ and $m\not \in A$ let $a_n=m+1/n.$ If $\inf A=-\infty$ let $a_n=-n.$...+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $m + \frac1n$ need not be in $A$, nor $-n$. So slightly some more care is needed in general. But it's not hard.

Comment: We don't need $m+1/n\in A$ in order for $\{(m+1/n,\infty):n\in \Bbb N\}$ to be an open cover of $A$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet true, I misunderstood.

Comment: Your A is fine but in this subject we always look for something simpler.  Of course you know that.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'll change the proof.